# How can I update this JSON array's values with angular.js & ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am trying to do JSON array which stores my applications settings.

I can't change those values and I don't know what to do

**Services.js:**

```
$localStorage = $localStorage.$default({
        settingsArray : [{"autoDelete" :false},{"deleteDate" : 0}]
    }); 

     var _changeDelDate = function(num){
            $localStorage.settingsArray.deleteDate = num;
        };
```

**controllers.js**

```
SettingsArray = StorageService.returnSettingsArray();
        $scope.range = SettingsArray[1];

        $scope.slider = function(num){     
            StorageService.changeDelDate(num);
        }
```

**settings.html**

```
       <ion-item class="item range range-positive" ng-show="value"> 
                <input type="range" name="volume" min="1" max="10" value="0" default="4" ng-model="range" ng-change="slider(range)">{{range}}
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: what exactly does not work?

Comment: why you are keeping your data in service ? it should be part of controller and from controller update the local storage accordingly.

Comment: Exactly. `$localStorage` is already a service. There is no need to wrap that in another service.

Comment: @AlexanderTaran JSON arrays values wont change.

Comment: that's because you don't change an array value. you are changing a property on array.
should be:
$localStorage.settingsArray[1].deleteDate = num;

Comment: @AlexanderTaran Thanks man it works! You are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't change an array value.
You are changing a property on array.
Should be: `$localStorage.settingsArray[1].deleteDate = num;`